# SQL Year over Year Performance with Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return year over year results based on date criteria. There is additional information I would like to include in the query i.e. first date of activity and first date of activity with spot name like '%6%'. The current query I have is multiplying the correct amounts by 6 and I can't figure out how to solve. When I remove the first "where" clause I get the correct amounts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select 
    V.IGB_License, 
    DBA, 
    V.Sci_Games_Name,
    convert(date,v2.Activity_date) as First6thMachineDate,
    convert(date,V3.Activity_date) as GoLiveDate,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2019' and DATEADD(YEAR,-2,getdate()-1)) then v.Funds_in else 0 end) as FundsIn2019,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2020' and DATEADD(YEAR,-1,getdate()-1)) then v.Funds_in else 0 end) as FundsIn2020,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2021' and getdate()) then v.Funds_in else 0 end) as FundsIn2021,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2019' and DATEADD(YEAR,-2,getdate()-1)) then v.Net_funds else 0 end) as NetFunds2019,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2020' and DATEADD(YEAR,-1,getdate()-1)) then v.Net_funds else 0 end) as NetFunds2020,
    sum(case when (v.Activity_date between '1/23/2021' and getdate()) then v.Net_funds else 0 end) as NetFunds2021
From VGT_activity V
    Left Join Locations on v.IGB_License = Locations.IGB_License
    left join VGT_activity V2 on v.IGB_License = v2.IGB_License
    Left join VGT_activity V3 on v.IGB_License = v3.IGB_License
Where v2.Activity_date = (
                        Select Min(V1.Activity_date)
                        From VGT_activity V1
                        Where v1.IGB_License = V2.IGB_License
                        and Spot_name like '%6%'
                            )
and v3.Activity_date = (
                        Select Min(V1.Activity_date)
                        From VGT_activity V1
                        Where v1.IGB_License = V3.IGB_License
                        )

group by V.IGB_License, dba, V.Sci_Games_Name, v2.Activity_date, v3.Activity_date
order by 4
```

Comment: Please show sample data + expected results. Extra values like that almost certainly comes from joins with duplicate rows which multiple the end result.

Comment: What type of sample data should I show? From each joined table or the end output from the current query?

Comment: Enough to create a [mre] i.e. the bare minimum that we can copy and paste out (so ideally DDL+DML) to run a test which replicates your issue.

Comment: Incidentally, looks like your query could do with using window functions instead of those subqueries